# Graphics: Can the frame buffer be allocated anywhere in memory?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, driver, low-level

I'm trying to figure out if the frame buffer - not some software concept, but the actual piece of memory holding the final video frame that is scanned out by the hardware to output it on a display - is in a special memory location.

Or is it the case that some memory is allocated at boot time somewhat randomly (maybe with some constraints applied), this memory gets designated as the frame buffer, and then the scan-out hardware is told at what address it resides?

Comment: You're talking about an iGPU built-in to the CPU, right?  Yes I *think* that's right.  Obviously a dedicated GPU with its own video RAM allocates the framebuffer somewhere in that video RAM, not main memory.

Comment: Depends on hardware design. There are both possibilities (cheaper one can use system memory).